# platform specific way (windows) to replace malloc (and other C allocation flavors)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, linker, malloc

I know that while c++ `::operator new` and associated flavors can be replaced/overridden, `malloc` (and `calloc` etc) can not.

However, is there still some (possibly platform specific) way to achieve the same (for example replace all `malloc` calls with an implementation that prints something to stdout on each allocation)? Using some linker magic maybe? In particular I want to replace the mallocs used by static libraries that I'm linking into my application (without altering those libraries code). I'm interested in solutions for windows, but if someone has a solution for another platform, that's certainly an interesting pointer as well.

Comment: This is called “interposition.” To find more, search for “interposition,” “interpose,” “interposing,” *et cetera*. Methods for achieving it are dependent on the build tools you are using (compiler, linker, operating system). Although you mention Windows, what tools are you using, Microsoft’s or some GCC port or something else?

Comment: For Linux you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is a path checked for link libraries *before* all other paths. And you can place a patched libc in that path that has a custom implementation of `malloc`. But it seems you are more likely looking for a **tool** to **debug** memory accesses. For that there is e.g. [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/). I am sure Windows has similar tools.

Comment: `#define malloc(...) call your function here`?

Comment: Sure.  It will depend on how those libraries are compiled.  In theory, they could be compiled with malloc being dynamically loaded from a DLL, or with malloc inlined into their code and lower level functions called from the OS.  Of course, by far the easiest is the way you ruled out (narrow modification of their source code or compilation process to add instrumentation)

Comment: @NathanOliver: “without altering those libraries code”.

Comment: You can override `malloc` on Windows in DLL CRT mode or in static CRT mode using `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` link flag. Make sure to cover all variants though, including _dbg versions. See `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\heap` for the CRT sources.

Comment: It should be possible to install a "hook" on HeapAlloc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am using Bazel and VS 2019 for building

Comment: @DevSolar no I want to have fine grained control over memory allocations to deal with NUMA performance issues

Comment: I would consider your chances of successfully dealing with NUMA performance issues with non-NUMA-aware third party libraries this way to be slim, but I wish you the best of luck...

Comment: in what problem call another function in place `malloc` or use macro. look how define `malloc` *crtdbg.h* - `#define   malloc(s)             _malloc_dbg(s, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)` -use self macro too

Answer (score 1):

Malloc can be overloaded or overridden. Check out this link to mi-malloc https://microsoft.github.io/mimalloc/overrides.html

Comment: Thank you that looks interesting, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

If using MSVC instead of using a different allocator I suggest that you take a look at the debug CRT's reporting options (this is where leak reports can be generated for example, using _CrtSetDbgFlag). You can also send the report text to a file using __CrtSetReportMode and _CrtSetReportFile.

The existing debug allocator is already very capable.